# Add custom cache driver in standalone Laravel cache instance

Tags: php, laravel-5

Using the cache component of Laravel ( `Illuminate/Cache` ) as caching backend for my app, how can I register a new custom cache driver? Since I don’t use Laravel at all (only `Illuminate/Cache`), I can’t add it to the service provider and the `Cache` facade returns and error.

Note that I’m successfully using the defaults drivers (file, memcached, redis) by passing the config and such inside an empty `Illuminate\Container\Container` using the `singleton` function:

*EDIT - Sample code how I get a cache store:*

```
$app = new Illuminate\Container\Container();

// Where $config is an array of config values
$app->singleton('config', function() use ($config) {
    return $config;
});

$app->singleton('files', function() {
    return new Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem();
});

$cacheManager = new CacheManager($app);

// Where $storeName is linked to the configs values
return $cacheManager->store($storeName);
```

Comment: Can you show you code if where you're "passing the config and such inside an empty `Illuminate\Container\Container`"? :)

Comment: Question edited

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#adding-custom-cache-drivers . Just replace the `Cache` facade with your `CacheManager` instance e.g. `$cacheManager->extend(...)`

Comment: I still get the `InvalidArgumentException: Driver [fooDriver] is not supported.` error

Comment: Turns out I had a typo in my driver name. Your solution works, thanks! You can post it as an answer if you want and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to make sure you driver extends the `Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store` interface.

Then you should just be able to do something like:

```
$cacheManager->extend('you-custom-driver-name', function ($app) use($cacheManager) {
    return $cacheManager->repository(new YourCustomDriver);
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#adding-custom-cache-drivers

Hope this helps!